# Mirror API static card insertion

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Started exploring on Glass app development and have a question relating to the Mirror API. I have downloaded the Mirror API quick start project for PHP and followed the step-by-step instructions : https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/php

Now my question is, on inserting a static card onto the glass, is it possible to automatically launch an existing app on the glass? Like instead of saying "Start a stopwatch", can the app launch be triggered on a static card insertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if automatic is possible, but you could use a custom uri scheme in a menu item to open your app, so the user doesnt get bombarded with random app launches

Comment: Hi Gert-jan.. Thanks for the response.. Have managed to insert a static card through Mirror API, with a OPEN_URI menu item having the app data-schema URI as payload.. And configured this same Data scheme in my Android Activity.. And the activity launch on menu item selection works great..                         https://plus.google.com/u/0/+DetAnsinn/posts/E1XqxCoNBD7

Comment: This seems to be the only possible solution at this point of time but is this the right solution?